# how is printf %i working in this situation?

Tags: c, arrays, struct, printf

Sorry trying to ask this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50812755/c-char-to-jstring-printf-works-for-int-type-but-not-for-string) in another manner.

```
typedef   struct 
 { 
    char duo_word[8]; 
 } duo_word;


  duo_word duo_word_inst = { .duo_word = { 'º', '\b', '\x1', '\0', 'À', '\xe', '2', 'a' } };

  printf("          %i ", duo_word_inst); // gives 67770 but how?
```

And how can I extract the 67770 value into e.g. an int variable?

Comment: This is undefined behavior. No need to go farther.

Answer (score 3):

The `%i` format specifier to `printf` expects an `int` as its argument.  However, you are passing a `duo_word`.  Using the wrong `printf` format specifier invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).  In this case, you're "lucky" it happens to print what you want, but you can't depend on that behavior.

Assuming the first 4 bytes in the struct represent a 32-bit integer in little endian format, you can pull out the individual bytes and set them in an integer as follows:

```
unsigned int value = 0;
value |= (unsigned char)duo_word_inst.duo_word[0];
value |= (unsigned char)duo_word_inst.duo_word[1] << 8;
value |= (unsigned char)duo_word_inst.duo_word[2] << 16;
value |= (unsigned char)duo_word_inst.duo_word[3] << 24;
```

Comment: It gives me -70 in value.

Comment: @Ali See my edit.  You need to cast each of the bytes to an unsigned value first.

Comment: can I use an unsigned long instead of an usigned int just to make sure I dont loose any part of the value?

Comment: @Ali An `unsigned long` is guaranteed to be at least 32-bit, so yes using that type should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

It's undefined behavior, so anything can happen.

What is likely to happen is `duo_word_inst` will simply be pasted on the stack
and `%i` will simply cause `printf` to slice `sizeof(int)` from that stack value.

You can do all of that manually and in a *defined* way by simply using `memcpy`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
typedef   struct 
 { 
    char duo_word[8]; 
 } duo_word;


int main()
{
    duo_word duo_word_inst = { .duo_word = { 'º', '\b', '\x1', '\0', 'À', '\xe', '2', 'a' } };
    int x;
    memcpy(&x, &duo_word_inst, sizeof(x));
    printf("          %i ", x); //prints 67770 too

#if UNDEFINED_BEHAVIOR
    printf("          %i ", duo_word_inst); // gives 67770 but how?
#endif
    return 0;
}
```

(An even better way would be to paste the value with bitops as in [dbush](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1687119/dbush)'s answer and thereby avoid implementation-defined behavior too.)

Answer (score 0):

Your code is likely the wrong solution to a different problem than the one you think you are solving.

First of all, an array `char [8]` cannot be used to reliably store integer values. This is because the `char` type has implementation-defined signedness. Meaning the compiler can implement it either as signed or unsigned, at a whim. And inside this, you store characters beyond the basic character, so there is no telling what your code will do.

If you wish to store raw data, you must use `uint8_t` from `stdint.h`.

Then as others have pointed out, you can't use `%i` to print a struct, nor to print a character array. If you are lucky, you get some kind of seemingly deterministic behavior, but formally this is completely undefined behavior. In your case it probably treated the bytes as a 4 byte little endian number, `'º', '\b', '\x1', '\0'` giving hex 00 01 08 BA, which in turn is dec 67770. The program might as well crash or print garbage though, since you rely on undefined behavior. It could work today and crash tomorrow.

In order to deterministically, portably and reliably get the value 67770, you can do something like this:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

typedef union
{
    uint8_t  bytes [8];
    uint32_t ints  [2];
} duo_word;

int main (void)
{
  duo_word dw = { .bytes = { 0xBA, 0x08, 0x01, 0x00 } };
  printf("%"PRIu32, dw.ints[0]);
}
```

This uses "type punning" through a union, which is ok in C (but not in C++). This still makes the assumption that you are using a little endian CPU however. For truly portable code, you have to use bit shifts instead.